# Keyboard authentication - SSH - add more questions

Tags: ssh

I read this article about [authentication methods for SSH](http://www.eldos.com/security/articles/1962.php)

This is what is written there?

During keyboard authentication zero or more prompts (questions) is presented to the user. The user should give the answer to each prompt (question). The number and contents of the questions are virtually not limited, so certain types of automated logins are also possible.

I run SSH server on Ubuntu. My question is how can I add more prompts(questions)? Now it prompts just for the password.

Thank you

Comment: I think you need to ask this on either http://ServerFault.com or http://askubuntu.com/ , as your question is more about the server configuration rather than about programming.

Comment: I thought that this magic place has an answer for everything :) Ok, thank you, I will try.

Answer (score 0):

This is accomplished using [PAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_authentication_module). [This](http://www.howtogeek.com/121650/how-to-secure-ssh-with-google-authenticators-two-factor-authentication/) is an example of using Google Authenticator module with SSH.
Depending on what you want to do, you'll probably want to write your own module. A good article about it can be found [here](https://www.packtpub.com/article/development-with-pluggable-authentication-modules-pam).